# relativelayout makes my button stop working

Tags: android, xml

when i use linearlayout everything works like its supposed except my button is at the top and not the bottom of the screen.

when i use relativelayout my button is on the bottom like its supposed to but only works for the first listview entry after that it stops working...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button android:id="@+id/plus"
android:background="@drawable/selector"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="75dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
/>

<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>

</ListView>



  <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/helptxt1"

  />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

..

```
 public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    //  @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            createNote();
        //    Intent intent = new Intent(context, QuoteEdit.class);
            //            startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });

 }


private void createNote() {
Intent i = new Intent(this, QuoteEdit.class);
startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this. A list view can expand indefinitely, and cannot be placed within a scrollview. Because of this, you probably won't be able to have a button below the list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your buttons wont work because when you use a Relative layout all the views/buttons are placed in the same location unless you place them above or below each other. Try doing this with your layout:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/plus"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/plus" >
</ListView>
```

or you can add an onClick to your button:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/plus"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:onClick="myClickMethod" />
```

and in your code

```
 public void myClickMethod(View view) {

      createNote();

 }
```